# How do I type the euro value sign € on a Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've tried bashing on my keyboard with the <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> key pressed with the <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> key pressed but I do not seem to be able to find how I can get the euro value sign.

<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> gives the dollar sign: **$**

What keystrokes do I need to use to get the euro **€** sign?

Comment: alt + shift + 2

Answer (score 169, accepted):

On an American English keyboard you can type the European Currency symbol (€) with <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

**NOTE:** It is also worth to note that specifically in Terminal, option 'Use Option as Meta Key' is turned on by default and this blocks this key combination. Please go to Terminal 'preferences', section 'Profiles' and under tab 'Keyboard' untick 'Use Option as Meta Key' checkbox to have it working.

Comment: I think that it is important to note that this only works if the font you are using has the € symbol available. For instance, I am working on a customer's menu, and they designed it using AG Buch BQ, which has no € symbol in the font.

Comment: There are several limitations. As you said the font must have that glyph available and it works on an American English keyboard. This may work on other keyboard layouts, but I can't attest to that.

Comment: @gavin every app I know will substitute a font that does include Euro if the currently active font is missing it.

Comment: @Tomg, I am working in InDesign, and InDesign did not do what you are talking about for this font. Although their is some amount of font substitution possible, in a Graphic Design environment, where you are sending customer files to a printing press, messing around with the customer fonts is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for that info, Gavin.  I didn't know that InDesign still worked this way.  Kind of defeats the purpose of using the Unicode standard, but I suppose it's useful in terms of letting users know their chosen font is not adequate for their text.

Comment: I am getting ™ on Big Sur - it is Opt-2 on mine

Comment: See @daniel's answer

Comment: Just for the record, **⌥ option + 2** works on my UK (British English) keyboard.

Answer (score 53):

On the Euro symbol's own official home page, there's a table of keyboard shortcuts for many national keyboards: http://www.eurosymbol.eu/mac-keyboard Copied and amended here:

```
keyboard layout keystroke combinations
Austrian        Option-Shift-D
Belgian         Option-$
British         Option-2
Catalan         Option-U
Dutch           Option-2
Finnish         Shift-4
French          Option-$
French (num)    Option -Shift-R
German          Option-E
Italian         Option-I
Italian - Pro   Option-E
Polish          Option-3
Portuguese      Option-3
Slovakian       Option-R
Spanish         Option-U
Spanish - ISO   Option-E
Swedish         Shift-4
Swiss French    Option-E
Swiss German    Option-E
U.S.            Option-Shift-2
```

Comment: there is no Polish layout listed any more

Comment: OK. Do you know if Option-3 still produces a €-sign on a Polish keyboard, or has it moved? My keyboard layout, Swedish, isn't listed either, but is printed on the key, so I have no problems finding it. ;-)

Comment: € typed viaa Option-3 on Polish kbd right now ;)

Comment: Should be top answer.

Comment: Correct  answer.

Comment: I confirm that this works perfectly on a French keyboard. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 50):

The Euro Currency symbol is found at <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on the US English keyboard.

In general, if you want to discover what symbols can be found on your keyboard when you press the modifier keys, you can use the Keyboard Viewer window.

To enable the Keyboard Viewer menu item

1. Make sure **System Preferences** » **Keyboard** » **Keyboard** » **Show Keyboard and Character Viewers in menu bar** is checked.

[image: Show Keyboard and Character Viewers in menu bar]

2. Make sure **System Preferences** » **Language & Text** » **Input Sources** » **Show Input menu in menu bar** is also checked.

[image: Show Input menu in menu bar]

Once you have the keyboard viewer enabled, go to the keyboard menu in your menu bar (it will look like either a picture of a keyboard or a flag representing the keyboard layout you have selected) and chose Keyboard Viewer. A window will appear with a picture of your keyboard. If you hold down the option, shift, or option **and** shift keys, it will show you what the keys on your keyboard do with those modifier keys pressed.

[image: keyboard viewer]

Comment: Option-Shift-2 ... is that on every Mac keyboard, or just on certain ones, like Canadian English?  (It also works on my US English setting.)

Comment: Not universal; it works on US English and Canadian English.

Comment: Upvote for also mentioning the Keyboard Viewer. I keep forgetting about it. € is opt+2 on UK keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

Just type alt and 2...... €
just those two keys

[Edit] Tested with British & Irish, [both use alt/2] US, Canadian & British-PC [use alt/shift/2] The alternate in each case gives ™
Very similar to the British/US 'pound' symbol, swapped between shift/3 or alt/3 depending on keyboard.

Comment: Why do you disagree with the other answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105206/237

Comment: Suspect it depends on the locale you are using, what hardware keyboard you are using etc, it's not going to be the same for everyone.  This one works for me, with a UK keyboard.  Perhaps the other answer is using a US layout.

Comment: Tested with British & Irish, [both use alt/2]  US, Canadian & British-PC [use alt/shift/2] The alternate in each case gives ™  Very similar to the British/US 'pound' symbol, swapped between shift/3 or alt/3 depending on keyboard.

Comment: gives me trade mark symbol: ™

Answer (score 5):

An option to use once you know how to get the **€** symbol is to create a text shortcut for the symbol on your Mac for faster typing. You can do this using text replacement.

To get started, follow these steps (also see image below for reference):

1. Launch **System Preferences** and click on **Keyboard** (Language & Text on previous versions of OS X).
2. Click on the **Text** tab.
3. The **Replace** and **With** columns appear. Click on the **+** button at bottom-left to add a new text shortcut, which opens a text field for you to type your trigger text, for example `euro`.
4. Press <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> key or mouse over to the adjacent text field (under the **With** column) and enter the actual **€** symbol. This becomes the resulting replacement text.

And you’re done. The next time you enter “euro” it will be replaced automatically with “€”.  But you can always press the Esc keyboard button (to cancel the text replacement) if you actually want to type out the word “euro”.

This also works for iOS devices under **Settings** → **General** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts**.

Please note that this does not work automatically in every app.  I’ve confirmed it works on iMessage, Notes, Reminders, Mail.

For iWork (e.g., Pages, Keynotes, Numbers) you’ll have to add the shortcuts as they use their own text replacement functionality. For example in Pages, click on the Pages menu item, then click on Auto-Correction tab, and add any text shortcuts in the same way as above. Here you can even choose to toggle (on or off) which text shortcuts you want to be active.

[image: Keyboard Text Replacement on Mac OS X]

Comment: Bad idea, try to type european ...

Comment: Typing "european" works fine, as text replacement only works on complete words. But yes, if you often need to type "euro" as a word, then a different shortcut would be advisable... I like to start my replacement strings with a special character to minimise accidental replacements, e.g. "#euro".

Answer (score 4):

## Character Viewer

The `Character Viewer` tool built into macOS offers the symbol you want, depending on what fonts you have installed.

To access, choose the `Show Emoji & Symbols` menu item in the icon menubar. May be named `Character Viewer` in older versions of macOS. Find the menu item next to `Keyboard Viewer` menu item.

If you do not see this menu amongst your icon menus, go to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard`. Check the `Show Input menu in menu bar`.

[image]

On the left, click the `Currency Symbols` grouping.

[image: screenshot of Character Viewer window]

Note the option to `Add to Favorites` on the right side. Convenient for frequent use.

Answer (score 2):

For Latvian keyboard layout on my mac the combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Polish OS X keyboard: <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: I thin k better to add to http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171466/237 with a comment that it is not from the site

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Czech Mac OSX keyboard, you will find € sign under combination of <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

just and addition here if you have you option key used to swap spaces this will override the keyboard shortcuts. Uncheck these options to key your true keyboard shortcuts back.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Instead of writing an answer to edit someone else's answer, simply click the **edit** or **improve this answer** button *below the post that you wish to improve*.

Answer (score 0):

On a Greek keyboard use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On my Greek one is alt + shift + 2

Comment: I am really curious what layout you could be using on a Mac.  As far as I know, Alt ε is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

## *UnicodeChecker* app

The free-of-cost [*UnicodeChecker*](https://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/) app for macOS lets you find and copy/paste any of the over 100,000 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). This includes [`EURO SIGN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign) with [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number 8,364.

This app also shows a list of fonts that include a [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) for this character.

Notice the menu item `Favorites` > `Add Current Codepoint to Favorites…`. If frequently used, you may find it convenient to add an item to the `Favorites` menu for this particular character.

[image: screenshot of UnicodeChecker.app with the Euro sign selected]

Answer (score -2):

It's <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> on my Croatian keyboard

Comment: Which keyboard, though? I use the U.S. Keyboard and I get this "ﬁ".

Comment: @IconDaemon Croatian

Answer (score -3):

2016 new MacBook Air. Euro sign is completed by pressing Alt key & 2.

Comment: What does this add that hasn't already been said? It doesn't even include the nationality of the keyboard.

Comment: Totally useless answer, should be deleted.

Answer (score -4):

On a British Mac keyboard, type [fn]-[alt]-2 to get €

Comment: That is not true - fn does not affect normal keys just the function keys - see this answer for UK keyboard alt-2

Answer (score -4):

Here's an easy way:

Just highlight and copy this: €

And then paste it into your email or whatever.

Comment: You forgot the additional... find this page again, scroll down to find this post... which may make it a less than optimal long-term solution ;)

Comment: Sure, but my real point was you can just Google "Euro symbol" and copy the symbol and paste it into any app. The time it would take someone to read through and implement any of these other solutions or memorize the key command for something they seldom use, copy/paste is something that is easily remembered and implemented.

Comment: Guess it depends where you live as to how seldom that would be.

Comment: Worst answer given here. There's nothing difficult about the Keyboard Viewer & Character Viewer options given. Both employ features in every Mac & transfer to many other obscure & seldom used characters.